Inspect AIP Label name for email in Microsoft Outlook using VBA
I have a user that is heavily invested in a VBA solution in legacy Windows Outlook.  He is trying to inspect the AIP label of the incoming emails in order to take action.
This appears to be stored in the property SensitivityLabel that is part of Excel VBA but this property does not exist in Outlook VBA. Office.SensitivityLabel also exists as part of the modern JavaScript based add-in model.
I am aware that the idenifiers for the labels are stored as message headers in the form:
MSIP_Label_abcdef0-1234-5678-90abc-def0123456
but I was wondering if there was a better way of getting these values without parsing headers.
